# Naive TensorFlow Model Question, how to match inputs and outputs to another model

Tags: c#, tensorflow, unity-game-engine

This is my first attempt at retraining a TensorFlow object detection model, which I'll then invoke from within Unity using C#.

The model from this repository works great: https://github.com/asus4/tf-lite-unity-sample/blob/master/Assets/StreamingAssets/coco_ssd_mobilenet_quant.tflite

So now I've retrained what I believe to be a similar model using this Google colab:
https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/tutorials/model_maker_object_detection
and that seemed to go smooth as well.

Loading my new model in Unity I see that the Invoke method is working, but getting the output tensors fails, the specific error being:
`Exception TensorFlow Lite operation failed. TensorFlowLite.Interpreter.GetOutputTensorData (System.Int32 outputTensorIndex, System.Array outputTensorData)`

And this is the line that causes that error:
`interpreter.GetOutputTensorData(0, outputs0);`

My naive assumption is that I'm incorrectly exporting the model and so I've taken screenshots of both models in Netron hoping that someone will look at the inputs and outputs and immediately see the issue.

Here is the working model:
[image: Model that works with my interpreter]

And here is the new one which does not work:
[image: Model that doesn't work with my interpreter]

I can see there are definitely differences in the quantization for both inputs and outputs as well as their formats and locations. Hoping those can be adjusted either when exporting the tflite model or rather in Unity where I invoke the model.

Thanks in advance for any guidance, the source code for C# is in the first link and I have not modified the Single Shot Detector from its current state.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else with the same issue it was actually just a matter of matching the Max_Detections parameter in Unity.

Comment: where to add this parameter? I am having simiar issue.

Comment: Sorry it's been a while since I touched that project, have you looked in Unity's inspector panel, specifically on the object that has this script attached?